# Gradle output of jar task as a dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a single task to produce a jar like this:

```
task contentJar(type: Jar, overwrite: true) {
...
}

artifacts {
    archives contentJar
}
```

How do I include the jar produced by the contentJar task as a testRuntime dependency?

I was able to define the dependency like this:

`testRuntime fileTree(dir: 'build/libs', include: '*content.jar')`

This works but is there a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: Are you adding a `testRuntime` dependency to an artifact produced by the same project? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

was able to do it like this

```
    dependencies {
        testRuntime contentJar.outputs.files
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your library project, Create a new configuration:

```
configurations {
  foo
}
```

Add your artifact to this configuration:

```
artifacts {
  foo contentJar
}
```

Use this project as a dependency in a different project, and use your configuration to limit artifacts to contentJar:

```
testCompile project(path: ':Library', configuration: 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the jar as artifact to some configuration, you can depend on that configuration.

Comment: Am I not already doing this? How do you "depend on that configuration" ?

Comment: Well, you add it as artifact tot he archives configuration. But you might want to add it e. g. as artifact to the compile configuration and thus automatically have it in your test classpath already if that is the semanitcally correct thing for your jar.

Comment: have you got an example of how I could add the artifact to the compile configuration?

Comment: `artifacts { compile contentJar }` just as you added to the `archives` configuration